# Como no duplicar data en MongoDB (con NodeJS), migrando desde MySQL

Tags: mysql, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy evaluando la posibilidad de empezar a trabajar con MongoDB haciendo uso de NodeJS, sin embargo, estoy formateado  para pensar en SQL y no en noSQL, me encuentro con el siguiente dilema el cual lleva un día masticando y todos los post/tutoriales parecen obviar esta parte así que: o no entiendo o mongoDB no se aplica a mi caso.

Tengo el siguiente caso de ejemplo (solo es para efectos de esta pregunta):

Si necesito guardar una venta en MySQL lo haría en tablas:

```
Cabecera de la venta
ID_VENTA | NUMERO | ID_CLIENTE | TOTAL
1        |  001   | 20         | 200

Detalle de la venta
ID_VENTA | ID_PRODUCTO | PRECIO_UNITARIO | CANTIDAD | TOTAL
1        |  5          | 15              | 4        | 60
1        |  78         | 14              | 10       | 140

Productos
ID_PRODUCTO | PRODUCTO |
5           |  CAMISA  |
78          |  ZAPATOS |

Clientes
ID_CLIENTE  | NOMBRE        |
20          |  JUAN PEREZ   |
150         |  ALBERTO RUIZ |
```

Esto mismo en MondoDB seria un solo documento:

```
{
    "NUMERO" : "1",
    "TOTAL" : "200",
    "CLIENTE" : "JUAN PEREZ",
    "DETALLE" : [
          {"PRODUCTO" : "CAMISA", "PRECIO_UNITARIO":"15", "CANTIDAD":"4"},
          {"PRODUCTO" : "ZAPATOS", "PRECIO_UNITARIO":"14", "CANTIDAD":"10"},
     ],

}
```

Ahora bien, podríamos tener documentos para cada cliente / productos, pero solo serian a modo de diccionario, ya que no llevarían relación directa con el detalle de la venta.

```
1.Para los Productos
[
    {"PRODUCTO" : "ZAPATOS"},
    {"PRODUCTO" : "CAMISA"},
]
2.Para los Clientes
[
    {"CLIENTE" : "JUAWN PEREZ"},
    {"CLIENTE" : "ALBERTO RUIZ"},
]
```

Y omitimos IDs, con lo cual me surgen las siguientes dudas:

1. Este modelo, ¿esta bien planteado?,
2. Y MAS IMPORTANTE: Imaginemos el caso real en el que la persona que carga los productos cargo "SAPATOS " en lugar de "zapatos", y se vendió durante 4 días y nadie se percató del error, en ese caso quedarían todos los documentos de ventas ingresados con el error. En un esquema relacional, solo cambio la tabla de PRODUCTOS, y al hacer los múltiples INNER JOIN no habría problema.

O cualquier otro caso de reporte, imagina si quiero obtener las ventas agrupadas por producto, obtendría las ventas de 4 días son SAPATOS y el resto con ZAPATOS.

Entiendo que al ser noSQL no acepta JOIN, sin embargo veo que hay "formas" de realizar los JOIN, a lo mejor buscando los IDs (asumiendo el caso de que emule las tablas relacionales) individualmente posterior al traer la tabla de cabecera.

Espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro y se que mas de uno habrá pasado por este problema y agradezco la mano que me puedan dar para resolverlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que no nunca llego la respuesta, pues después de leer mucho y hacer varias pruebas pruebas, lo que quiero hacer no es posible o mas bien no se debe de hacer debido a que es exactamente la definición de bases de datos relacionales.

Existen algunos emuladores que intentan recorrer la data e ir actualizando pero son lentos y al final termina siendo mejor usar SQL.

Si lo que necesitas es guardar la relación como explico en la pregunta, usa un motor SQL, ya que un motor basado en documentos no sirve para este propósito.